# Laravel Middleware -> get the logged in user

Tags: laravel, middleware

I want to write my own middleware to check, if the current user is member of a certain grup. If yes, the user can move on to the route, if not, the user will be redirected to a different page.

My middleware is working, but I don't know how to get the current users id. I've tried the Auth::user() method, but with no success.

This is my Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use App\Usergroups;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserGroupMiddleware
{
     /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $group = NULL)
    {
        $user_id = $request->user()->user_id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $usergroup = Usergroups::find($user->benutzergruppe);

        if($usergroup->slug == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but with no success` in this case? If the user is logged in you should be able to check it like this: `if(Auth::check()) { print Auth::user()->id; }`

Comment: Using the Auth::user() method gives me nothing. It's empty. No values. If I set the "benutzergruppe" to a valid value, I can pass. But even in my view the Auth::user() method has no values. No error is thrown, but if I try to access a existing value from a user entry it gives my the message that I'm trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have access to the currently authenticated user, *if it’s been resolved*. That means you need to make sure you place your group-checking middleware *after* the `auth` middleware on your route/route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'in_group:group_name']], function () {
    // Routes
});
```

You can then check a role like this:

```
class UserGroupMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $group)
    {
        // Check user is in specified group here
        if ($request->user()->memberOf($group)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // Display a 403 Forbidden error
        abort(403);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your hint brought me on the right way. But it didn't worked the way you described it.

Answer (score -3):

Like **Martin Bean** said, I had to include another middleware. But in this case it wasn't the auth-middlewar. I had to include the web-middleware in my routes.php.

routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'admingroup']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', 'TestController@index');
});
```

UserGroupMiddleware.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use App\Usergroups;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserGroupMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $group = NULL)
    {
        if(Auth::user()){
            $user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
            $user = User::find($user_id);
            $usergroup = Usergroups::find($user->benutzergruppe);

            if($usergroup->slug === 'admin'){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        abort(403, 'No Access');
    }
}
```

Before I wrote the middleware, I ran the

```
php artisan make:auth
```

command. So all views an controlles have been created by laravel.

Important: Don't forget to register the middleware in your Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

        // Custom Middleware
        'admingroup' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserGroupMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Why are you getting the ID of a _user object_, just to hit the database to get the same user again? Just use `$request->user()`.

Comment: This code is doing the same as Martin's in a more obtuse way.